# Sketchup tag rename needed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

We have two Sketchup tags: [sketch-up](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sketch-up) and [google-sketchup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-sketchup).  They both refer to the same program and neither tag name is correct.

The first has five questions and the tag was created with an incorrect name and no wiki summary.  It might have been intended to refer to sketching applications in general, but that duplicates the [drawing] tag, so it is unnecessary for that purpose.  All five of these questions also have the [google-sketchup] tag, so the [sketch-up] tag is entirely redundant and can be deleted.

The second has 34 questions and a wiki summary.  Sketchup was created by Google, but is now owned by Trimble, so the google part of the tag is incorrect.  The Trimble name is not well known, so replacing google with trimble would be more confusing than useful.  Sketchup is a trademarked name, so no company name is really necessary.

Suggestion: Rename [google-sketchup] to [sketchup].  The wiki summary will also need to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Done. [sketchup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sketchup) now  has all those questions.

Feel free to provide a short tag wiki.

Comment: Done.  Updated and expanded the existing one.